# ROW_NUMBER() in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

How to use ROW_NUMBER() in where clause in DB2 database.
 I have tried below but it did not work:

```
SELECT * FROM CSPAPP.LOCATIONS
WHERE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOCATION)) BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

It gave error : Invalid use of aggregate function or OLAP function.

I also tried with followiong ways :

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOCATION)) AS RN ,* FROM CSPAPP.LOCATIONS
WHERE RN < 200

SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOCATION)) AS RN ,LOCATION FROM CSPAPP.LOCATIONS
WHERE RN < 200
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't reference an alias on the same level where it is defined. You need to wrap this into a derived table:

```
SELECT location
FROM (
   SELECT row_number() over(order by location) as rn, 
          location 
   FROM cspapp.locations
)   
WHERE rn < 200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution but it is partially serving my prupose. I am trying SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT row_number() over(order by location) as rn ,*         
   FROM cspapp.locations
)   
WHERE rn < 200     But it is not working.Can you suggest.

Comment: oops.Sorry. Error was : "Unexpected token * was found following 'by location) as rn.Expected Tokens may include :<select_sublist>." I can not enter every column because there are about 600 columns in the table.So I have to use * to select all columns in one go.

Comment: Maybe `location` is a reserved word in DB2, I don't know

Comment: I think select column_name,*  from Table_name is not allowed in DB2 which is allowed in SQL Server. Any idea ???

Comment: Then prefix the `*`: `select row_number() ... , table_name.* from table_name` (or use an alias)

Comment: @Mandar to access the rn colunm defined in the inner select you would have to create an alias for it, after the eclosing parentesis for the inner select as " as my_alias" and then modify your  where clause my_alias.rn < 200

Answer (score 6):

I use something like this when selecting based on row number in iSeries DB2:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY location) as RRN, *
    FROM CSPAPP.LOCATIONS
    )
WHERE RRN between 100 and 200
```

If you are only interested in the 1 field you may be able to assign a name to the select and reference the fields:

```
SELECT DATA.location
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY location) as RRN, *
    FROM CSPAPP.LOCATIONS
    ) as DATA
WHERE DATA.RRN between 100 and 200
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried something like this :SELECT * FROM  cspapp.locations WHERE LOCATION IN ( SELECT location FROM ( SELECT row_number() over(order by location) as rno,LOCATION FROM cspapp.locations)   WHERE rno BETWEEN 1000 AND 10000) .It worked.

Answer (score 3):

You could try FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY instead of row_number. Write your select as you would normally without ROW_NUMBER, order by whatever you need and FETCH FIRST x.

selecting all columns with "*" is not a good practice *especially* if you have 600+ columns (and that by itself is bad design of the database).

Answer (score 2):

Without using row_number() function:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM CSPAPP.LOCATIONS ORDER BY LOCATION FETCH FIRST 200 rows only)
ORDER BY LOCATION DESC FETCH FIRST 100 rows only;

With Row number:

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOCATIONS), LOCATIONS as RNM FROM 
(SELECT * FROM CSPAPP.LOCATIONS ORDER BY LOCATIONS FETCH FIRST 200 rows only)
ORDER BY LOCATIONS DESC FETCH FIRST 100 rows only;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reference an alias on the same level where it is defined. You need to wrap this into a derived table:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM(
       SELECT row_number() over(order by location) as rn ,L.* 
       FROM cspapp.locations L) As T1 
WHERE T1.rn < 200
```

But you should understand `*`  is never be a best practice. You should use the column name rather than `*` (`L.col1`).